# How to create/import bare node.js module (without express) with IntelliJ

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea

Default node.js module gets created with express, adds all the dependencies and forces me to remove all these files afterwards.

Isn't there any other way to create simple node.js project without express while keeping all remaining seetings (`node_modules` marked accordingly etc.)? Was trying to google around but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please vote for the related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12988